# Prestashop 1.6: unable to show manufacturer logo in manufacturer page

Tags: php, image, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing an e-commerce using Prestashop 1.6.1.3.
I have a problem that I can't solve: in the manufacturer page of my website I am not able to see the manufacturer logos (see the screenshot).
[image]

In the manufacturer table the logo is present and I regenerated the prestashop miniatures too, so I can't understand why the images are not loaded in that page.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: any messages about missed "original" files during miniatures regeneration process? Show us the code where logo placed on page

Comment: No error during the process

Comment: Are you sure if the images are in the folder ´img/m´ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: the problem was related to the logo image size.
I had to set the height and width of the image from: Preferences -> Images